# How to open url using tab based layout in Android application?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview

I am developing Android application which has 3 tabs.

1. On first tab I want to display web page (HTML/XML) contents with some information.
2. When user clicks on the other tab, it should open a url without showing address bar in same window.

Any inputs/example for reference would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html